# data manipulation with leap year

Tags: r, datetime, data-manipulation, leap-year

Here is my `data`:

```
date1
2015-01-01
2015-02-28
2015-03-15
2016-01-20
2016-02-29
2016-03-01
```

I want to create a new column `nextyear`. (ex. `date1`=2015-01-01, `nextyear`=2016-01-01)
So, I try:

```
data[, nextyear := date1 + months(12)]
```

However, I didn't consider **leap year**.
(ex. `date1`=2015-02-28, `nextyear`=2016-02-29)
(ex. `date1`=2016-02-29, `nextyear`=2017-02-28)

I know `SAS` has a `INTNX` function:

```
nextyear=intnx('YEAR', date1, 1, 'SAME');
```

How can I do in `R`?

I know there is a function in `lubridate`

```
ymd("2016-2-29") %m+% years(1)
[1] "2017-02-28"
ymd("2015-2-28") %m+% years(1)
[1] "2016-02-28"
```

When date is previous one year to leap year(ex. 2015), this function not work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Sotos I know. I edit my question. When date is 2015-02-28, the function not work

Comment: That's because you will have an extra row. Study the question I linked